# What does np.polyfit do and return?

Tags: python, numpy

I went through the docs but I'm not able to interpret correctly

IN my code, I wanted to find a line that goes through 2 points(x1,y1), (x2,y2), so I've used 
    np.polyfit((x1,x2),(y1,y2),1)
since its a 1 degree polynomial(a straight line)

It returns me [ -1.04 727.2 ]
Though my code (which is a much larger file) runs properly, and does what it is intended to do - i want to understand what this is returning

I'm assuming polyfit returns a line(curved, straight, whatever) that satisfies(goes through) the points given to it, so how can a line be represented with 2 points which it is returning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [numpy.polyfit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) documentation:

> Returns:
>
> p : ndarray, shape (deg + 1,) or (deg + 1, K)
>
> Polynomial coefficients, highest power first. If y was 2-D, the coefficients for k-th data set are in p[:,k].

So these numbers are the coefficients of your polynomial. Thus, in your case:

y = -1.04*x + 727.2

By the way, numpy.polyfit will only return an equation that goes through all the points (say you have N) if the degree of the polynomial is at least N-1. Otherwise, it will return a best fit that minimises the squared error.

Answer (score 0):

These are essentially the beta and the alpha values for the given data.
Where beta necessarily demonstrates the degree of volatility or the slope